# pynvrtc on Google Colab: libnvrtc.so not found

Tags: python, cuda, google-colaboratory

In a Google Colab notebook, I am installing a python package which uses pynvrtc to compile some CUDA codes.

I got the error:

```
OSError: libnvrtc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I run `!find / -name 'libnvrtc.*'` and get

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so.8.0.61
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so.8.0
```

My question is: Do I suppose to have `libnvrtc.so` in my Google Colab system? How can I get around if I just have `libnvrtc.so.8.0`?

Comment: What is the Python library you are trying to use?

Comment: Is your  python installation actually 64 bit?

Comment: Yes. I believe Google Colab is 64 bit. The library is https://github.com/jonas-koehler/s2cnn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to make pynvrtc work. Create symbolic link for `libnvrtc.so`.

```
!apt -y install libnvrtc8.0
!ln -snf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so.8.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so
```

Motivated by [Is it possible to install cupy on google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135065/is-it-possible-to-install-cupy-on-google-colab)