# No module named 'cupy' on Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, google-colaboratory, cupy

I'm working on the FastPhotoStyle project:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/FastPhotoStyle

and I follow the steps of its tutorial:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/FastPhotoStyle/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

I'm running Example 1 on Google Colab where default environment is

- CUDA 10.0
- Python 3.6
- Chainer 5.4.0
- CuPy 5.4.0

This is how I tried on Colab Notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oBgdJgXCLlUQhpwPoG1Uom3OKTzHR4BF

After running

```
!python3 demo.py --output_image_path results/example1.png
```

Here's the error message I got:

> Traceback (most recent call last):     File "demo.py", line 9, in
>
> import process_stylization
>
> File "/content/drive/FastPhotoStyle/process_stylization.py", line 14,
>   in
>
> from smooth_filter import smooth_filter
>
> File "/content/drive/FastPhotoStyle/smooth_filter.py", line 327, in
>
> from cupy.cuda import function
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cupy'

Could someone help me with it please?

Comment: did you do `pip install cupy` ?

Comment: I did. <!CUDA_PATH=/opt/nvidia/cuda pip3 install cupy>. and it shows "Successfully installed cupy-6.0.0"

Comment: Maybe this is related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135065/is-it-possible-to-install-cupy-on-google-colab

Comment: @corochann Thanks. I've already seen this post which basically says Colab has a built-in CuPy. I've tried the built-in Cupy, but it popped up the same error <ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cupy'>. I then installed CuPy manually via <!CUDA_PATH=/opt/nvidia/cuda pip3 install cupy>, but the same error occured.

Comment: How about trying uninstall exsiting cupy `pip uninstall cupy` (please type this more than **2 times** to verify all installed cupy version existed in system are uninstalled). And install cupy with `pip install cupy --no-cache-dir`? --no-cache-dir option is important to re-build cupy from source.

Comment: @corochann If I uninstall some built-in package in Colab (such as CuPy 5.4.0) today, will Colab automatically restore it when I restart the kernel tomorrow? If not, I'm afraid that I could mess up with CuPy, especially when it comes to environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried running the demo with python full path?

```
!/usr/local/lib/python3.6//bin/python3 demo.py --output_image_path
```

or running without anaconda installation by simple install all necessary libraries

```
!pip install cupy
```

or see installation instructions  [here](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html)

Comment: thanks! I'm working on it. So far, it seems Anaconda is the problem.

Comment: @AmberJi any luck?

Answer (score -1):

```
import time 
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
s = time.time()
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,1000))
C = A.transpose()
e = time.time()
print("waktu CPU:",e - s, "detik")

s = time.time()
A = cp.random.radint (10,size=(1000,1000))
C = A. transpose()
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()`enter code here`
e = time.time()
print("waktu GPU:",e - s, "detik")
```

Comment: This does not address the question at all. Please read through [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).